# Hive UDF in Java - Conversion from binary to hexadecimal

Tags: java, mongodb, hive

I have a requirement to convert a binary to hexadecimal. The issue is very similar to the one mentioned in below link but i need to use java instead of node.js - [Converting mongodb Binary _id to LUUID using node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789342/converting-mongodb-binary-id-to-luuid-using-node)

The column value is a binary base64  represented as a data type string in Hive. "AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==".
The required hex output - '00018e06-1de9-aa45-afb5-a2bc00ed94f7'

I am creating a Hive UDF in Java to do this conversion and I am working on Hive 1.0 version. I wanted to represent (not convert) this string "AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==" as a base64 to further convert to hex.

Similar to the node.js example in the above link - 
 var hex = new Buffer(bin, 'base64').toString('hex');

However base64 doesnt seem to be valid.

Is there a way to do it without Hive UDF ? If not, how can we represent (not convert) the string column as a base64 column.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Let us understand this. You have AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w== in some db column's cell right ? And you have decided to show it in hexa-decimal format in your HTML. Is that right ?

Comment: Hi Surajit,  That is correct (except for the HTML). There is a string column in db that has value AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==  (which is binary base64) and I need to convert to its equivalent hexadecimal format - '00018e06-1de9-aa45-afb5-a2bc00ed94f7'

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend you to use Apache Common Codec
Your string looks like a base64 string.

In **Java**, Use :

```
String data = "AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w==";
byte[] bytesOfBase64 = Base64.decodeBase64(data);
String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(bytesOfBase64);
System.out.println(hexString);
```

Reference [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611248/java-convert-base64-to-hex-string/#41611662)

In **JavaScript**, Use:

```
function base64toHEX(base64) {

  var raw = atob(base64);

  var HEX = '';

  for ( i = 0; i < raw.length; i++ ) {

    var _hex = raw.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)

    HEX += (_hex.length==2?_hex:'0'+_hex);

  }
  return HEX.toUpperCase();

}

console.log(base64toHEX("AAGOBh3pqkWvtaK8AO2U9w=="));
```

Reference [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460182/decode-base64-to-hexadecimal-string-with-javascript/#39460727):

Comment: @Suraj, if so, please choose vote for my answer and chose the solution (green tick)...it will help me. Thanks.

Comment: Surajit..I tried to do so number of times..but the sys says the upvote is recorded but will not display publicly as I do not have enough reputations yet. (new to stack overflow).