# How to convert a base64 string into hex in android?

Tags: java, android, base64, hex

I am getting a base64 string. How do I convert it to hex.
I tried the followind but it isn't working

```
String guid = "YxRfXk827kPgkmMUX15PNg==";
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(guid);
String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(decoded);
System.out.println(hexString);
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working ? Do you have a reference ? What's the output ?

Comment: Hex.encodeHexString is not working.. Its showing deprecated

Comment: What exactly "isn't working"? Wrong results? Missing imports?

Comment: Look at this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611248/java-convert-base64-to-hex-string

Comment: @user2433953 "deprecated" doesn't mean it's not working, that's a compiler warning. Whats the output of your code?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java

Answer (score 1):

```
String guid = "YxRfXk827kPgkmMUX15PNg==";
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(guid);
String result = HexUtil.toHex(decoded);
```

the hexUtil class :

```
public class HexUtil{ 
    private static final char[] DIGITS = {
                '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
    };

    public static final String toHex(byte[] data) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte d : data) {
            sb.append(DIGITS[(d >>> 4) & 0x0F]);
            sb.append(DIGITS[d & 0x0F]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```