# Java aes encryption string to hex

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using node forge package to encrypt and decrypt on my server , now I am  trying to encrypt data from my client app on android and want to send data back to my server in hex format but the below code is not working

```
val KEY_AES= "************"
val IV_AES= "************"
fun encrypat(value: String): String? {
    try {
        val key: ByteArray = KEY_AES.toByteArray()
        val ivs: ByteArray = IV_AES.toByteArray()
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
        val paramSpec: AlgorithmParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(ivs)
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, paramSpec)
        return Hex.encodeHexString(cipher.doFinal(value.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))),true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

error :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeHexString([BZ)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar)

Comment: @blackapps , I do not want base64 string , I want hex format , edited to show the error

Comment: Well.. NoSuchMethodError. What is it that you wanna know?

Comment: @blackapps all stackoverflow answers for hex show this function

Comment: @blackapps required libraries are all added , even used common 1.3

Comment: Show some stackoverflow answers.. Links.

Comment: What variable type does cipher.doFinal()  return?

Comment: Did you try the non static method?

Comment: I used this one to encrypt : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232705/encrypt-text-to-aes-cbc-pkcs7padding

and these ones to change the data to hex : 1-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611248/java-convert-base64-to-hex-string
2-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126567/method-not-found-using-digestutils-in-android

used many others also still does not work

Comment: What i miss in your question is if you have problems with encryption or with encoding to hex.

Comment: @blackapps cipher.dofinal returns bytearray

Comment: @blackapps encryption is working now need to encode to hex instead of base64

Comment: I do not understand that you would use Hex.encodeHexString() if you have to hexencode a byte array. I would rather think  something like Hex.encodeByteArray().

Answer (score 1):

You are using the legacy version of apache.http.
But you should be able to get the same results with the available `char[] encodeHex(byte[] data)` method.

Comment: your answer with char[] encodeHex lead me to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top 

now it works , Thanks alot